# Java Language Conversion Assistant 2.0 - Upgrade error while install

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio-2012, j#, visualj#

I want to convert my java code to C#..

I google it somebody told use JLCA[Java Language Conversion Assistant 2.0]

But i have problem on that.. when i install JLCA 2.0.. It display the error as

> The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows installer service
> because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade parch
> may update a different version of the program. verify that the program
> to upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch

How install JLCA..

And i have visual studio 2013 and 2010 in my system..

How to solve this problem please help..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Same problem here, did you find an alternative?

Comment: no dude i didnt get any solution on above question :(